# Array value validation error for checking existing data

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

Array value validation error the option else statement is not working 
I need to check whether the value are existing or not in array using jquery

```
   $(document).ready(function (){
   $('.txtbox').focusout(function () {
    var bind = [10];
    var data = $(this).val();

            for (var j = 0; j < 10; j++) {
                if (bind[j] == data) {
                    alert("This Name Is Already Exist");
                    $(this).val("");
                    $(this).focus();                        
                }
                else {
                    bind[j] = data;
                }
            }
      });
     });
```

Html Code:

```
 <input type="text" class = "txtbox" id="0"/>
 <input type="text" class = "txtbox" id="1"/>
 <input type="text" class = "txtbox" id="2"/>
```

Comment: [fiddle](http://fiddle.jshell.net/) ur code !!!

Comment: and share ur html code

Comment: i dont know how i can use fiddle

Comment: ok share ur html code

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have just one element in data and in second iteration `bind[j] == data` will through exception as there is still *one* element in array and you are trying to access second element as `j=1` point to second element of array. This results in exception. You better using indexOf to find element in array. Also declare array outside event handler to make it global so that it holds data until next `focusout` call.

**[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Ft685/)**

```
$(document).ready(function (){
   var bind = [];
   var j = 0;
   $('.txtbox').focusout(function () {       
        var data = $(this).val();           
        if (bind.indexOf(data) != -1) {
             alert("This Name Is Already Exist");
             $(this).val("");
             $(this).focus();                        
        }
        else {
            bind[j++] = data;
       }            
    });
});
```

Comment: where i can use indexOf

Comment: Its also not going to else part friend pls help me

Comment: Yes friend i m using your answer only but it didn't shown any error and then i put one alert message also in your conditions but both alert is not displayed

Comment: Ensure jquery is added and did you check the demo?

Comment: Hai if i want to search array[5] value is it possible then tis code is usefull to me

Answer (score 1):

var bind = [10]; doesn't create an Array of Size 10 ...instead an Array containing only one element.Hence you cannot apply a loop of 10 iterations to that array!

Comment: then how i can set the iteration

Comment: use 
for(var i=0;i<bind.length;i++)

Comment: initailise using  fro ex. var bind=[10,20,30,40]